# Find same observations of a list/matrix in another matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

For a marketing class I have to write a function that calculates the retention rate of the customers (probability that a customer still is a customer). I've come so far that I isolated the ids of the individual customers and stored them in the matrix first.transactions.data. I then split them into cohorts (group of customers by time) with split() and stored them in the list cohort.
Now comes my problem: I calculated another sub-matrix from the full data set called final.period.data where I will calculate the retention rate. However, therefore I have to isolate the ids in final.period.data for each cohort. My instructor told me that I should create an additional column in final.period.data that shows TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the cohort's id and final.period.data's id are the same. For this I tried to use exists, but I always receive error messages. I tried the following:

```
final.period.data <- if(exists(cohort$'1'$id, where = final.period.data$id) final.period.data$same = TRUE)
```

but always receive error messages such as: unexpected symbol or invalid first argument. I also tried to convert the list cohort into a matrix but this didn't help either. How do I have to change the exist command or is there a simpler way to locate cohort's ids in final.period.data?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a function that does what you want:

```
funct <-(final.period.data){
 if (final.period.data$cohort =='1' & final.period.data$id ==<condition2>){
   #Change the number for the TRUE condition}
 else{ #If it doesn't fit the two conditions
  #Change the number for the FALSE condition}
}
vector <- c(nrow(final.period.data))
final.period.data <- cbind(vector)
```

And use it as the apply function. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/2886003) will you find more information about apply
But I usually do it with a for loop, first creating the new column and then adding it to the data frame.